# Why doesn't my Perl DBI query return any results in a CGI script?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm using DBI for the first time (and not long started Perl [2 weeks]) and I can't seem to get any results from the database. Here's what I have:

```
if( defined( $get{findAllPages} ) && defined( $post{ki} ) ){

   my ($database, $hostname, $port, $password, $user );

   $database = "#########";
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $password = "#########";
   $user = "###########";
   my $KI = $post{ki};

   # connect to the database
   my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;";
   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE KI = '" . $dbh->quote($KI) . "' ") or die "Could not select from table";
   $sth->execute();
   if( $sth->rows != 0 ) {
      my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
      my $domain = $ref->{website};
      my $DB_username = $ref->{db_name};
      my $DB_password = $ref->{db_pass};
      $sth->finish();
      $dbh->disconnect();

      print "domian: " . $domain . "<br />\n";

      chomp(my $url = trim($domain));
```

As it stands it checks to see if `KI` is correct and then checks row amount which works. The bit I can't get to work is returning values from the array;

```
my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
my $domain = $ref->{website};
my $DB_username = $ref->{db_name};
my $DB_password = $ref->{db_pass};
```

If anyone can let me know where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI)'s error handling to see what's wrong. See [Programming the Perl DBI, chapter 4](http://oreilly.com/catalog/perldbi/chapter/ch04.html) (Error handling) or ["DBI::mysql error handling" on Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=437578) for references.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me if "or die" works in online cgi files as I can never seem to get it to output to the browser.

Comment: fetch() without execute().. so im guessing...
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;";
   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE KI = '" . $dbh->quote($KI) . "' ") or die "Could not select from table";
   $sth->execute();
   if( $sth->rows != 0 ) {
      my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
      $ref->execute();
      print $DBI::errstr;
      my $domain = $ref->{website};
      my $DB_username = $ref->{db_name};
      my $DB_password = $ref->{db_pass};
      $sth->finish();
      $dbh->disconnect();
shuld do it

Comment: if you are using cgi, one method is to use CGI::Carp. see http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html#MAKING-PERL-ERRORS-APPEAR-IN-THE-BROWSER-WINDOW. by the way, post your code in your question, not in the comments because the formatting is bad.

Comment: grrr... it works fine when I run from cmd on my local machine but when I use via browser tells me to do one thing, then when i go back to my local machine that change i made causes an error...

Comment: What does the browser tell you to do?

Answer (score 0):

What I often do when I can't see what is going on:

use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = $sth->fetch();

print Dumper $ref;

and you'll see the data structure layout. Sometimes it is a matter of incorrect indexing into an array or hash.